# Wordpress dynamic child page without 404

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to create a subpage, e.g. /test/ and everything that I enter after /test/ should have one specific template and indexing, no 404 error.

I wanted to make this with virtual pages, but it's too many url's to add. (tried here - [Wordpress fake/virtual folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67868222/wordpress-fake-virtual-folder))

I've got my template page-*pagename*.php which works. Now I need to add that every child of test does not return 404.

I think I have already searched the entire internet and cannot find a solution to this task

Answer (score 0):

What you could fiddle with is with grabbing the main query on 'template_include'. You add an action like this. You can add it to your child theme in functions or in your custom plugin.

```
add_action( 'template_include', 'custom_router' );
```

Then in the custom router function, you can check the parameters that you are requesting ('test') and redirect to a template of your choice. Also add in functions.php or in custom plugin. Place a template file in the relevant path.

```
function custom_router( $query ) {
     global $wp_query;

        if($wp_query->query['name'] == 'test') :


        var_dump($wp_query->query['name']);
        var_dump($wp_query->query['page']);

        return dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/some-template.php';

        endif;

}
```

I tested the code in the latest wordpress version with a custom plugin and the default theme btw.

Comment: Thank you very much for response. I've done this a little different than you.
I added a new page *pagename* and stick page-*pagename*.php to my theme folder.

Then i used $title['title'] = get_query_var('*some-var*'); in my page-.. template to forced title change. 
Then i added to functions.php
`
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^*SOME-FOLDER-NAME*/?([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=*pagename-id*&*some-var*=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
`
Now i got mydomain.com/custom-folder-name/ and then i can add everthing i want :)